# Where is PATH set from, when you delete PATH?

Tags: windows, path

In short, it appears if I delete the PATH it reverts to a default. This is good, but I am curious what is setting it to this default value.

```
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

I have removed the `PATH` value under these keys

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Environment
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet002\Control\Session Manager\Environment
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment
```

Then relog Windows, and it comes back with the default `PATH`. My guess is that this default value is stored inside the `explorer.exe` file, but input is welcome.

Comment: Does removal of those registry settings affect what you can see in you r "Environment Variables"? On XP, go to "My Computer", right click -> Properties -> Advanced -> Environment Variables. This will show you user variables and system variables.

Comment: @MrMoose yes. After deleting registry values `PATH` does not show up on the page you mentioned.

Comment: Looking at some [other](http://superuser.com/questions/113646/restoring-windows-xp-path-variable) [posts](http://superuser.com/questions/284342/what-are-path-and-other-environment-variables-and-how-can-i-set-or-use-them) on SuperUser, it seems as though it is possible to delete the PATH variable, so I'm not entirely sure whats happened in your situation. How do you know it is still set? Is it via Windows-R and being able to run something, or is it by opening the command window and doing an ECHO %PATH%? If it is the latter, then is there anything in your autoexec.bat/config.sys files?

Comment: @MrMoose this is for Windows 7, `autoexec.bat` and such does not apply that I can tell.